# synchronous call and merging bodies results with async

Tags: node.js, express, node-async, node-request

This is a result from TheMovieDatabase

```
"results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/k1QUCjNAkfRpWfm1dVJGUmVHzGv.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Based upon Marvel Comics’ most unconventional anti-hero, DEADPOOL tells the origin story of former Special Forces operative turned mercenary Wade Wilson, who after being subjected to a rogue experiment that leaves him with accelerated healing powers, adopts the alter ego Deadpool. Armed with his new abilities and a dark, twisted sense of humor, Deadpool hunts down the man who nearly destroyed his life.",
      "release_date": "2016-02-09",
      "genre_ids": [
        35,
        12,
        28,
        878
      ],
      "id": 293660,
      "original_title": "Deadpool",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "Deadpool",
      "backdrop_path": "/n1y094tVDFATSzkTnFxoGZ1qNsG.jpg",
      "popularity": 43.515295,
      "vote_count": 192,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.46
    }]
```

I need to make a call to the itunes api too, using the original_title and merge the properties of each object of the array. If I have collision on property name I don't mind.

It looks something like that for now :

```
request({
        uri: url,
        method: 'GET'
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        // The movie Database results
        previousBody = JSON.parse(body);

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            resultBody = JSON.parse(body);
            async.each(resultBody.results, function (element, callback) {
                // ITunes api call
                request({
                    uri: searchEndPoint + qs.stringify({
                        term: element.original_title,
                        media: 'movie',
                        entity: 'movie',
                        limit: 1
                    }),
                    method: 'GET'
                }, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                        // I want to append to the results of item in 'element' and send it back in the res

                        res.write(JSON.stringify(_.extend(element, JSON.parse(body))));
                    } else {
                        errorCallback(res, error, response, body);
                    }
                });
                callback()
            });

        } else {
            errorCallback(res, error, response, body);
        }
    }
);
```

I want to send back the result when done with all the itunes results have been parse and added to the response.

Edit : new code :

```
        var fullResults = [];
    request({
            uri: url,
            method: 'GET'
        },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                var resultBody = JSON.parse(body);
                async.map(resultBody.results, function (element, callback) {
                        request({
                            uri: searchEndPoint + qs.stringify({
                                term: element.original_title,
                                media: 'movie',
                                entity: 'movie',
                                limit: 1
                            }),
                            method: 'GET'
                        }, function (error, response, body) {
                            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                                fullResults.push(JSON.stringify(_.extend(element, JSON.parse(body))));
                                callback();
                            } else {
                                errorCallback(res, error, response, body);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            errorCallback(res, err, response, body);
                        } else {
                            resultBody.results = fullResults;
                            res.status(200).send(resultBody);
                        }
                    });

            } else {
                errorCallback(res, error, response, body);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You can't keep writing JSON to your response like that. There are also syntax errors, and you'd probably want to use a map function instead.

Comment: callback() should be called inside the callback of request and use map instead of each

Comment: While looking at the documentation of async I missed something the 3rd parameter so I added it and it solved my problem and I fixed the rewriting my json by another way, can I post and answer to my question?

Comment: I added the new code to the question it probably can be better

Answer (score -1):

Try this. i have used async **map** function

```
request({
            uri: url,
            method: 'GET'
        },
        function(error, response, body) {
            // The movie Database results
            previousBody = JSON.parse(body);

            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                resultBody = JSON.parse(body);
                async.map(resultBody.results.map(function(element) {
                        return function(callback) {
                            // ITunes api call
                            request({
                                uri: searchEndPoint + qs.stringify({
                                    term: element.original_title,
                                    media: 'movie',
                                    entity: 'movie',
                                    limit: 1
                                }),
                                method: 'GET'
                            }, function(error, response, body) {
                                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                                    // I want to append to the results of item in 'element' and send it back in the res

                                    res.write(JSON.stringify(_.extend(element, JSON.parse(body))));
                                    return callback({
                                        error: error,
                                        body: body,
                                        response: response
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    return callback();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    }, function(err) {
                        return errorCallback( err.error, err.response, err.body);
                    });

                } else {
                    return errorCallback(res, error, response, body);
                }
            })
```

Comment: It won't 100% work because of ```res.write(JSON.stringify(_.extend(element, JSON.parse(body))));```

Comment: I added my working code but we can probably make it better